# What values are allowed in the HTML Editor?

Tags: html, css, knowledge

In creating a Knowledge Article, I was adding an `img` to it. I decided to flip over to the source view and add in a `style="border: 1px solid black;"` for a border and, after saving, the value of `style` gets stripped away.

I figured this was normal security stuff so I then went looking for what values are acceptable. I found [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_using_html_editor.htm), which lists what HTML and attributes are allowed. However, what I don't understand, is that the attribute `border` is allowed but apparently the `style="border..."` isn't even though that page doesn't list any restriction like that.

Is there anything that lists something more complete as to what values are allowed in the style tag?